# Updating user using azure-graphapi module for Node js

Tags: node.js, azure, restify, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying out to update an user on my Azure account using Node.js technology. I'm using azure-graphapi module to send request and initialize.
Following is my code.

```
var GraphAPI = require('azure-graphapi');
var graph = new GraphAPI(appSettings.oauthOptions.tenantId, appSettings.oauthOptions.clientId, appSettings.oauthOptions.clientSecret);
var reqHeaders = { "content-type": "application/json" };
var reqBody = {
            "department": "Sales",
            "usageLocation": "US"
        }
    var person = {
        userId: userID
    };

graph.patch('users/f0eceb4f-xxxx-409a-xxxx-4e3exx4e3157', JSON.stringify(reqBody), reqHeaders, function (err, user) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(user);
        }
        else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

Even after providing content-Type header it is throwing me an error as "{ [Error: Graph API Error: 400 (Bad Request) Content-Type header value missing.] statusCode: 400 }"

It would be of great help if any one can help me out on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There several mistakes in this module you are using. To make the code work, we should do some additional modifications in the source code `GraphAPI.js` in `node_modules/auzre-graphapi`:

Start with [Line 195](https://github.com/fhellwig/azure-graphapi/blob/master/GraphAPI.js#L195), there is an `if` condition stmt, the author seems forget to define the `content` which is used since [line 199](https://github.com/fhellwig/azure-graphapi/blob/master/GraphAPI.js#L199), and only if you have to parse the post body to `buffer` object, it will set the content-type header. So, we can quickly modify the code as:

```
if (data) {
        if (Buffer.isBuffer(data)) {
            options.headers['Content-Type'] = contentType;
        } else if (!contentType) {
            content = data;
            if (typeof content === 'string') {
                options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
                options.headers['Content-Length'] = content.length;
            } else if (content !== null && typeof content === 'object') {
                content = JSON.stringify(content);
                options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
                options.headers['Content-Length'] = content.length;
            }
        } else {
            if (typeof contentType === 'string') {
                options.headers['Content-Type'] = contentType;
            } else if (contentType['Content-type'] !== null) {
                options.headers['Content-Type'] = contentType['Content-type'];
            }
        }
    }
```

And then set the header as your code: `var reqHeaders = { "Content-type": "application/json" };`

BTW, as the [update user document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#UpdateUser) refers, it will response 204 without response body if success, so your code will print "undefined" if success.

## update 4/19/2016

As the author doesn't maintenance the package any more, and he has created a new package [graph-service](https://github.com/fhellwig/graph-service) for universal Graph APIs. Refer to  https://github.com/fhellwig/azure-graphapi/issues/5#issuecomment-211392546